# PHP - Two lines of code to print string multiple times

Tags: php, recursion, counter, repeat

I need some guidance with a exercise I was set as part of my PHP class. I've tried many different methods but none that satisfy the requirements. The task is to do the following:

*Prerequisite :*

1. Without using any variation of a loop
2. Without any variation of string repeat
3. Without string join function
4. Without the require statement
5. Using only 4 lines of code

   - It's worth noting that each statement must be on it's own line and the `<?php`, `?>` tags count as one line each.

*Output:* print the following text 200 times

> “All work and no play makes jack a dull boy.”

I'm assuming it requires the use of a while loop but I've exhausted my knowledge of PHP and simply can't come up with a solution. I'm not necessarily looking for the answer just to be pointed in the right direction.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you allowed to use arrays? Are you not allowed to use `str_repeat()`?

Comment: Arrays can be used, but not str_repeat().

Comment: So what does your teacher say about labels and goto? :)

Comment: You can save 1 line of code because you should not put the `?>` in place unless you're writing other (non-PHP) code after the PHP code. So all you need is the `<?php` opener, thus you can use three lines....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if I got it or not, but heres my try...

```
function printsth ($count) {
    echo $count++, "All work and no play makes jack a dull boy.<br>", $count <= 200 ? printsth($count++) : "";
}
printsth(1);
```

cleaner version

```
function printsth ($count) {
    echo "All work and no play makes jack a dull boy.<br>", $count++ < 200 ? printsth($count++) : "";
}
printsth(1);
```

Comment: updated the function name as it collapses with php reserved function name

Comment: This was actually very close to the solution I came up with in the end, which was indeed correct, however instead of the ternary operator I used an if statement to check the count and to also call the print function. I should note it was valid to use an if statement and an echo on the same line and finally omitting the closing PHP tag brings it to a total of 5 lines :)

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
$i = 0;
while ($i++ < 200){
    echo("All work and no play makes jack a dull boy.");
}
```

Comment: I would add that the brackets are optional and the whole `while()`&`echo` statement can be set to one line

Comment: This is actually the solution that I thought was correct, but I had forgotten to mention that it must be done without using any variation of a loop so I'm assuming it requires a recursive function. Since the closing PHP tag can be omitted, it leaves 4 lines for the code and 1 line for the opening PHP tag which is 5 lines in total. It's a very tricky question.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, since you can use arrays this makes it relatively simple:

I recommend browsing just this page and seeing what functions are available to you : https://secure.php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php

If the idea is to use recursive functions then this solution defeats the purpose and maybe the teacher will want future restrictions on using any built-in php functions aside from echo/print.

First solution if `array_fill()` is acceptable:

```
<?php
echo implode( "<br/>\n", array_fill(0, 200, "All work and no play makes jack a dull boy.") );
```

If you can't use `array_fill()` and it seems `<?php` is considered one of the four line requirement then here's this spaghetto:

```
<?php
a: (isset($i)?++$i:$i=0);
echo "<!-- $i --> All work and no play makes jack a dull boy.<br/>\n";
if ( $i < 199 ) goto a;
```

... And if line 2 is disallowed then I say this:

```
<?php
a:
echo "<!-- ".(isset($i)?++$i:$i=0)." --> All work and no play makes jack a dull boy.<br/>\n";
if ( $i < 199 ) goto a;
```

Comment: this is actually a pretty cool way to get it done. but doesn't `array_fill` has the conflict with the rule of any variation of string repeat ?

Comment: @Andrew I wondered about this also. Not sure if the answer would be accepted by the teacher. I was looking at the other solutions for ideas to reduce them to 3 lines.

Comment: this is an interesting question...I also wonder what the answer would be given by the professor

Comment: The topic we we're covering was using functions and recursion so I think my professor was looking for a solution that involved those two. However the solutions you provided are very good nonetheless, thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution, using recursion and anonymous function (just for fun).

```
$rec = function($iteration, $text) use (&$rec) {
    return $iteration == 200 ? '' : $text .= $rec(++$iteration,"All work and no play makes jack a dull boy.\n");
};
echo $rec(1,'');
```

Comment: I don't have much experience using anonymous functions, however I was informed by my professor that it is possible to shorten the code to 4 lines (including the <?php tag) using anonymous functions so perhaps I'll look into them at some point, thank you.